# Is the mortality problem for orthogonal matrices undecidable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logic, computability, orthogonal-matrices

It is known that the mortality problem for 3×3 matrices with integer entries is undecidable. Is the mortality problem for 3×3 **orthogonal** matrices still undecidable ?

The mortality problem: determining, given a finite set of n × n matrices with integer entries, whether they can be multiplied in some order, possibly with repetition, to yield the zero matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Orthogonal matrices are invertible, therefore it's a fairly easy property to check: it never happens.